# Angular 7.x, ag-grid 19.1.4, ag-grid: invalid colDef property 'singleClickEdit'

Tags: ag-grid-angular

I'm locked to ag-grid-enterprise 19.1.4. I'm getting the warning:

ag-grid: invalid colDef property 'singleClickEdit'

Yet looking at the source-code for 19.1.4, the interface export interface ColDef has the property.

```
       This is a column definition:
```

{
                headerName: 'Foo', field: 'foo_data', editable: true,
                valueSetter: this.valSetter,
                valueGetter: this.valGetter,
                singleClickEdit: 'true',
                cellEditor: 'agRichSelectCellEditor', cellEditorParams: this.getFooList
            },

Everything works as expected when running the application. I get single-click editing. However the warning is unexpected.